# Displaying 'favourite' content

Tags: profile

On a feed of images, 3 images per column, instagram profile like, making an image the size of two columns is suggesting that the image is 'favourite' in any way?

[image]

LE: The content is being favourised by the user. Basically, the user is going to add some pictures (of products or anything that he can think of) to his profile and mark some of them as favourite (as in, how much he would like to have them or travel there), so he can receive some 'alerts' regarding the favored content.

I'd like to know if this would be descriptive enough for the rest of the users that would visit a profile. Is the learning curve too big?

Unfortunately I do not have more mock ups to share as this is very early in the dev stage.

Comment: Please provide context for the problem. Is this content being favorited by the user? What other actions can they take? What is the domain? a photo viewer? News content?
Do you have more descriptive images or mocks you can share?

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for your answer. I have edited the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no alternative to descriptions or labels other than **Descriptions** or **Labels**

Make a **Favorites** tab in the user's profile or have a **Favorites** section that stays on top of the image feed. This could be followed by a **More photos** section that lists out the remaining photos in a reverse chronological order.

*PS: Do not consider any app's or company's design methodology as a **standard**. Users cannot be expected to understand that implication without training*

Answer (score 0):

I do not think enlarging one of the photo items is intuitive enough for users since it is not a standard indicator of favorite-status on other websites.  If you were absolutely attached to this method, you could provide a brief tutorial upon sign-up explaining the significane but this is not recommended as users don't always read. Instead, consider appealing to the user's pre-existing understanding of how favorited items are handled on other websites.  For example, put an outline of a star or heart icon in the corner of each image that when selected, fills in with solid color.  Like Shreyas wrote, I would also suggest a separate section or tab that allows the user to only look at these items that were marked favorite so they can quickly access them later rather than trying to find them again in the list of all items.